# nginx or dns url rewrite or masking based on path

Tags: nginx, dns, resolve, white-labelling

I work on one website which is travel blog and there is sub section `mytravelsite.com/tickets` which is whitelabel and everything under that `mytravelsite.com/tickets/fares` and other pages are pointing to another ip and this works fine.

But now i would like to switch and now main site to be `mytravelsite.com` which would be whitelabel from `mytravelsite.com/tickets` but without `/tickets` in url but still keep my blog so another trouble is that whitelabel don't have `robots.txt` so this i would have to serve too from my hosting.

So in the end i have hosting with `10.1.1.1` ip and whitelabel that resolve to `10.10.10.10` ip

What i need is:

everything under `mytravelsite.com/blog` to resolve to my hosting and my hosted website on `10.1.1.1`
and also `mytravelsite.com/robots.txt` and `mytravelsite.com/sitemap.xml` to resolve to my hosting on `10.1.1.1`

and everything else to resolve to the whitelabel at `10.10.10.10`

i am guessing that this can be done either with some dns setup or nginx proxy or rewrite rules but everything i searched on internet for last 2 days ended up in failure.

Answer (score 0):

DNS only considers the name, i.e. the part before the slash.  You have always `mytravelsite.com`, so this can't be done purely in DNS.

*I know this isn't a real/full answer.*

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve it using proxy.

The included snippet is not a configuration of `nginx` but of an `apache` as I don't have similar setup for `nginx` within my reach now. But I believe it can be useful starting point though.

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
    ServerName mytravelsite.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /blog/ http://10.1.1.1/ retry=1 timeout=600 keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://10.1.1.1/

    ProxyPass /robots.txt http://10.1.1.1/ retry=1 timeout=600 keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /robots.txt http://10.1.1.1/

    ProxyPass /sitemap.xml http://10.1.1.1/ retry=1 timeout=600 keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /sitemap.xml http://10.1.1.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Notes:

- `10.*.*.*` is a local-only network, so the `10.10.10.10` within the
  virtualhost header is just for an illustration on *what* server this
  definition should be put.
- It also will not be working out of the box - just start here and
  iterate to a final solution
- You have not defined how could "your hosted website" be identified, therefore it is missing in the example